# Can't find path when requesting from API endpoint

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I'm having trouble finding the right path when requesting data from this API (Food Standards Agency), specifically Ratings. I keep getting this error: "The API 'ratings' doesn't exist"

I'm new to this so would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction?

This is a link to the documentation: https://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/Help/Api/GET-Ratings

This is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/ratings"
#params = {}
headers = {"x-api-version": 2,
            "accept": "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json"
            }

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using your `headers`

It should be within your request: `response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)`